# Steps to connect MongoDB and Solr using DataImportHandler

Tags: mongodb, solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I am new to SOLR and MONGODB.

I am trying to index data from mongodb into SOLR using DataImportHandler but I could not find the exact steps that I need to follow.

Could you please help me in getting the exact steps to index MongoDB into Solr using DataImportHandler?

SolrVersion - solr-4.6.0

MongoDB version- 2.2.7

Answer (score 25):

Late to answer, however thought people might find it useful.

Below are the steps for importing data from mongodb to Solr 4.7.0 using DataImportHandler.

## Step 1:

Assume that your Mongodb has following database and collection

```
Database Name: Test
Collection Name: sample
```

The `sample` collection has following documents

```
db.sample.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c0c6666ee638a21198793b"), "Name" : "Rahul", "EmpNumber" : 452123 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c0c7486ee638a21198793c"), "Name" : "Manohar", "EmpNumber" : 784521 }
```

## Step 2:

Create a `lib` folder in your solrhome folder( which has `bin` and `collection1` folders)

add below jar files to `lib` folder. You can download solr-mongo-importer from  [here](https://github.com/james75/SolrMongoImporter/downloads)!

```
- solr-dataimporthandler-4.7.0.jar
- solr-mongo-importer-1.0.0.jar 
- mongo-java-driver-2.10.1.jar (this is the mongo java driver)
```

## Step 3:

Declare Solr fields in schema.xml(assumed that id is already defined by default)

add below fields in schema.xml inside the `<fields> </fields>` tag.

```
 <field name="Name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="EmployeeNumber" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

## Step 4:

Declare data-config file in solrconfig.xml by adding below code inside `<config> </config>` tag.

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">  
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

## Step 5:

Create a data-config.xml file in the path collection1\conf\ (which by default holds  solrconfig.xml and schema.xml)

data-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="MyMongo" type="MongoDataSource" database="Test" />
<document name="import">
 <!-- if query="" then it imports everything -->
     <entity  processor="MongoEntityProcessor"
             query="{Name:'Rahul'}"
             collection="sample"   
             datasource="MyMongo"
             transformer="MongoMapperTransformer" name="sample_entity">

               <!--  If mongoField name and the field declared in schema.xml are same than no need to declare below.
                     If not same than you have to refer the mongoField to field in schema.xml
                    ( Ex: mongoField="EmpNumber" to name="EmployeeNumber"). -->                                              

           <field column="_id"  name="id"/>               
           <field column="EmpNumber" name="EmployeeNumber" mongoField="EmpNumber"/>                            
       </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

## Step 6:

Assuming solr (I have used port 8080) and mongodb are running, open the following link http://localhost:8080/solr/dataimport?command=full-import in your browser for importing data from mongodb to solr.

fields imported are _id,Name and EmpNumber(MongoDB) as id,Name and EmployeeNumber(Solr).

You can see the result in  `http://localhost:8080/solr/query?q=*`

Comment: 1.if you want change your query with respect to parameter you can mention `query="{Parameter}" ` in `processor="MongoEntityProcessor"`

Comment: 2.you can use the following configuration for collection in version 5.1 `solr-5.1.0\server\solr\configsets\basic_configs\conf` as `SolrHome\collection\conf` and along with this `solr-5.1.0\server\solr\solr.xml` as  `SolrHome\solr.xml`

Comment: I'm new to Solr and I really need to index data from MongoDB into Solr to make search queries, I tried mongo-connector but it doen't show any error but the terminal is stuck with "Logging to mongo-connector.log" so I followed your steps to the letter and when it did configure the dataimportHandler however it doesn't retrieve the data from mongoDB , I'm guessing it's something to do with "data-config.xml ", a driver to mention maybe ? could you please help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [SolrMongoImporter](https://github.com/james75/SolrMongoImporter/), it ask you to import 2 libraries into your solr proyect and create a data-config.xml.

You probably will need to import in your solrconfig.xml the following libraries if you don't have it

```
  <lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```

Comment: For me there are some performance issues for  SolrMongoImporter on bigger mongoDB. So I tried mongoSolrImporter, which was 10x faster, because of multithreading. ->  https://github.com/5missions/mongoSolrImporter

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed everything above and still facing the issue: check whether you have multiple jars in different locations.

i.e.

- {solr-home}/dist/solr-dataimporthandler-8.10.0.jar
- {solr-home}/server/libs/solr-dataimporthandler-8.10.0.jar
- {solr-home}/server/solr/core/libs/solr-dataimporthandler-8.10.0.jar

If so, remove the jar files from everywhere but the location you have configured in the `solrconfig.xml` file.