# Connect remote MongoDB to Solr using DataImportHandler

Tags: mongodb, solr, dataimporthandler

Having my MongoDB server and Solr on the same machine I was able to connect them using DataImportHandler with help from : [Steps to connect MongoDB and Solr using DataImportHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450555/steps-to-connect-mongodb-and-solr-using-dataimporthandler) , now I have MongoDB and Solr on different machines and in the Solr config I added the URL of MongoDB but I didn't succeed.
Could anyone tell me how to indicate to Solr that MongoDB is in a distant server ?

Thanks

Comment: Any success in importing from mongo? I'm in the same situation.