# Best approach to integrate ASP.NET MVC3 app with Solr

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, solr, solrnet

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 web app that uses MongoDB.
I am trying to implement search using Solr.

I want only the Title, Tags fields to be indexed by Solr and returned.
In future I may include the bigger Description field.

I am looking at this but I am not clueless on how to proceed from here.
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_0/tutorial.html

MongoDB also has Solr connector. This confusing to me.

Could anyone please suggest what would be a better approach to take?

Completely decouple Solr from MongoDB and add from web app side OR use mongoDB connector?

If this is not the right place or not a right question, I can remove this.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you to proceed is to use [SolrNet](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet). SolrNet will give you more access over what your code does compared to MongoDB Solr Connector (written in Python).

References:

1. [How to use mongoDB with Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659600/how-to-use-mongodb-with-solr)

Comment: I am not going to use Solr due to the scalability issues with Solr.