# What is the proper way to perform a contextual search against NoSQL key-value pairs?

Tags: python, mysql, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

With MySQL, I might search through a table "photos" looking for matching titles as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
WHERE title LIKE '[string]%';
```

If the field "title" is indexed, this would perform rather efficiently. I might even set a FULLTEXT index on the title field to perform substring matching.

What is a good strategy for performing a similar search against a NoSQL table of photos, like Amazon's DynamoDB, in the format:

{key} -> photo_id,
{value} -> {photo_id = 2332532532235,
                   title = 'this is a title'}

I suppose one way would be to search the contents of each entry's value and return matches. But this seems pretty inefficient, especially when the data set gets very large.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Knowing which specific NoSQL solution you have in mind would probably help in answering.

Comment: Updated. I'm looking into Amazon's DynamoDB

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453872/full-text-search-in-nosql-databases

Comment: Deleted my ans as it made no sense after update ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a Mongo shell example.

From the basic tutorial on MongoDB site:

```
j = { name : "mongo" };
t = { x : 3 };
db.things.save(j);
db.things.save(t);
```

So you now have a collection called things and have stored two documents in it.

Suppose you now want to do the equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM things WHERE name like 'mon%'
```

In SQL, this would have returned you the "mongo" record.

In Mongo Shell, you can do this:

```
db.things.find({name:{$regex:'mon'}}).forEach(printjson);
```

This returns the "mongo" document.

Hope this helps.

Atish

Comment: You are right - that would be the correct way - I should have used the pure Regex form - this will return "%mon%" actually.