# How to search a string in databases of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

This Query can search any string value (table name, table data etc) from all the tables/views of any SQL Server database, when you will place any string at "**your text here**" it will search your given string from all the tables/views exist in that database,

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100) 
    SET @SearchStr = 'your text here'

DECLARE @Results TABLE(ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM @Results
```

**But I like to search** given string in the `procedures/functions/triggers` as well is there any query exist in SQL Server 2005. As this query does not search in these areas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> search given string in the procedures/functions/triggers

This is actually far easier.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), definition
  FROM sys.sql_modules
 WHERE definition LIKE '%'+@SearchStr+'%'
```

One way to use it is to add it to the end of your TSQL code, i.e modify the last SELECT:

```
SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue
  FROM @Results
 UNION ALL
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), definition
  FROM sys.sql_modules
 WHERE definition LIKE '%'+@SearchStr+'%'
```

Personally, I'd just run them separately one after the other as separate statements.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the view [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx).

Or, in pre-2005 versions of SQL Server, [syscomments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260393%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: syscomments is seriously lacking, esp. with the text broken over multiple records. This causes text searched to sometimes be missed on long modules.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a helpful query to find something like proc etc from msDB means this will find table/function/proc ref in SQL Server Agent's Jobs.

```
USE [msdb] 
GO 
SELECT j.job_id, s.srvname, j.name, js.step_id, js.command, j.enabled 
FROM dbo.sysjobs j 
JOIN dbo.sysjobsteps js ON js.job_id = j.job_id  
JOIN master.dbo.sysservers s     ON s.srvid = j.originating_server_id 
WHERE js.command LIKE N'%YOUR TEXT HERE%'
```

Where query above in accepted answer

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%'+@SearchStr+'%'
```

only work to find the given text in procedures/functions/triggers from selected DB.

Below query works to check the job status of SQL Server Agent Jobs:

```
SELECT sj.name
   , sja.*
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sja
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS sj ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
```

Query to find the constraints details of a table in DB.

```
SELECT
    FK_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
    FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
    PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
    PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
    Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                i1.TABLE_NAME,
                i2.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            WHERE
                i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
           ) PT
    ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE PT.table_name = 'Table Name'
```

To check the SQL Job Agent running job status:

```
use msdb                          
go                         
SELECT  j.name JobName            
, STUFF(STUFF(h.run_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-') as Date
, CAST(STR(h.run_date, 8, 0) AS DATETIME) + CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST (h.run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6),5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') AS DATETIME) AS StartDate
, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) + CAST(h.run_duration as varchar(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') AS DURATION
, CASE h.run_status               
          WHEN 0 THEN 'failed'           
          WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeded'         
          WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'            
          WHEN 3 THEN 'Cancelled'        
          WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress'      
        END AS ExecutionStatus           

FROM    sysjobhistory h           
        INNER JOIN sysjobs j             
            ON j.job_id = h.job_id       
                     WHERE STEP_ID = 0
                     AND CAST(STR(h.run_date, 8, 0) AS DATETIME) + CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST (h.run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6),5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)>=getdate()-90
                     AND (j.name Like 'DW%' 
                     )
ORDER BY j.name, STUFF(STUFF(h.run_date,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')
```

So this can be helpful for someone searching some text in DB.

Here is the query to find definition of SP/view/trigger etc in sql server.

```
SELECT definition   
FROM sys.sql_modules  
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Object Name Here');
```

To view Table schema we can use F1 and for full details, we can use the following query as well

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.COLUMN_NAME, C.IS_NULLABLE, C.DATA_TYPE, TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, C.COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
FULL JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS CC ON C.COLUMN_NAME = CC.COLUMN_NAME 
FULL JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC ON CC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'Table Name Here';
```